# Cartesian product in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I have two different sets for example {e1, e2, e3} type of E1 and {g1, g2, g3} type of E2 which defined as follows:

```
E1 = DeclareSort('E1')
e1,e2,e3 = Consts('e1 e2 e3', E1)

E2 = DeclareSort('E2')
g1,g2,g3 = Consts('g1 g2 g3', E2)
```

My question is how can I make Z3 give me a Cartesian product between the two sets. I need the result like following:
{(e1, g1),(e1, g2),(e1, g3),(e2, g1),(e2, g2),(e2, g3),(e3, g1),(e3, g2),(e3, g3)}.

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that e1,e2, e3, g1, g2, g3 are variables. They are not different by definition. So, the assertion e1 == e2 is satisfiable.
You can create products in Python in the usual way:

```
 [(x,y) for x in [e1,e2,e3] for y in [g1,g2,g3]]
```

If you want to create the product of two sorts, you can use algebraic data-types.
Declare a datatype "Tuple"

```
>>> Tuple = Datatype('Tuple')
>>> Tuple.declare('mk_tuple', (('first', E1), ('second', E2)))
>>> Tuple = CreateDatatypes(Tuple)[0]
>>> Tuple.mk_tuple(e1, g1)
mk_tuple(e1, g1)
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake.  e1,e2, e3, g1, g2, g3 are different.  {e1, e2, e3} type of E1 and {g1, g2, g3} type of E2.

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj, but in this case I need to assign all tuples manually. Can z3 do the same as the itertools.product() dose, as the second answer shows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for x in itertools.product(['e1', 'e2', 'e3'], ['g1', 'g2', 'g3']):
...   print(x)
...
('e1', 'g1')
('e1', 'g2')
('e1', 'g3')
('e2', 'g1')
('e2', 'g2')
('e2', 'g3')
('e3', 'g1')
('e3', 'g2')
('e3', 'g3')
>>>
```